# How to tunnel private adress based on etc/host record?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, tunneling

I have machine A (MacOS), and Server B in private network (ubuntu). In etc/host on B I have something like:

```
192.168.63.123 abc.abc.com 
192.168.63.123 abc2.abc2.com 
192.168.63.123 abc3.abc3.com
```

I am trying to see content from 192.168.63.123 abc.abc.com on machine A. What have I tried is:

1. I ran ssh tunnel `ssh -g -L 1234:abc.abc.com:80 admin@publicIP` it did not work.
2. I tried to configure proxy using command: `ssh admin@publicIP -D 1234` and
   [network-settings-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc9Zk.png) It did not work, while accessing abc.abc.com in browser on A

**How to do it?**

I have trouble with asking proper question but I think I have described it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your setup. `ssh -g -L 1234:abc.abc.com:80 admin@publicIP` should work assuming publicIP is an IP of server B.

I think you have to crosscheck it:

1. `ping abc.abc.com` from server B. It works?
2. `wget abc.abc.com` from server B. It works?
3. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` should have `AllowTcpForwarding yes`
4. When ssh client is connected what happens if you try `wget localhost:1234` ?

ssh server is always complaining if it is unable to connect tunneled host, so if you have `/etc/hosts` problem - you will see some error.